# Active Directory in EC2: Can't create new users

Tags: active-directory, amazon-ec2, directory-services

I'm trying to set up a series of EC2 instances running Windows Server 2012 connected with Active Directory. This is a new AWS account and I've only done the following: created a VPC with a public and private subnet, plus another subnet in another region (required for SimpleAD). In AWS Directory Services, I created a Simple AD. I then launched a t2.micro instance and joined it to the AD. So far so good.

I then logged in with the Admin account and went to Active Directory Users and Computers, right-clicked on the domain name and selected New > User. But after I type the information and password and choose Next, I get the message "An error ocurred. Contact your system administrator."

I followed the AWS instructions up to this point, but I'm not sure where I've could gone wrong. Nothing I tried seems to have helped, and now I'm a bit lost. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by 2 Windows updates:

- KB3000850
- KB2992611

To fix the problem:

1. Uninstall these 2 updates.
2. Confirm you can add new users.
3. Install this update as a replacent for the above 2 updates: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3000850
4. Confirm you can still add new users.

Note: The above resolution was given to me by AWS Support when I reported this same issue to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this issue by adding users at the command prompt:

```
net user myUser myPassword /add /domain
```

Once done most other management tasks can be performed in Active Directory Users and Computers.